# Failed to instantiate module in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an index.html file, where I use 'logOut' directive from 'logoutModule' and 'ProductService' from 'productModule'.

However, it is unable to load 'logoutModule' in IE. It works fine in all other browsers.

I have an app.js file,

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['logoutModule','productModule']);
```

I have logoutModule.js file,

```
var logApp = angular.module("logoutModule",[]);
logApp.controller("logOutController",['$scope',function($scope){

$scope.logout=function(){           
    window.location.href ='https://google.com'; 
    sessionStorage.clear();
} 
}])
.directive("logOut", function(){
return {
 template:`<img class="logout" ng-src="./image/cmdSignout24.svg" ng-click="logout()">`,
 controller:'logOutController'
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet explorer doesn't support back tick. try replacing it with double 
quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced the following code :

    ``<img class="logout" ng-src="./image/cmdSignout24.svg" ng-click="logout()">``
with:

     `"<img class='logout' ng-src='./image/cmdSignout24.svg' ng-click='logout()'>"`